# Garbage Collection in Java with Recursive Function

Tags: java, recursion, garbage-collection

I know that objects become unreachable and marked for garbage collection in every iteration of a regular loop. What about recursive calls? Something like:

```java
public void doWork() {

    Object a = new Object();

    ....some work with a...

    this.sleep(60000);
    doWork();


  }
```

Is the object (i.e. 'a') in the first recursion marked for garbage collection once the second recursion begins or does it need to be explicitly marked null since the outer function never finishes because of the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During each recursive call the local variables(here the reference "a") are pushed onto the stack. Local variable are GC roots. During the second recursive call the new reference is pushed onto the stack. However, the first reference is still there and thus the object is still reachable and thus can't be garbage collected.

Thus if you want the first created object to be marked for garbage collection(while the function hasn't yet finished) you should explicitly set "a" to null.

Here is a useful link to understand GC: http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx

Comment: By the definition of reachability, an object referred to by a local variable becomes unreachable as soon as execution proceeds past the last read of the variable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Do you mean to say that if I write to an object without reading its value later on, then the write will not be done (optimized out if no thread is reading its value after it is written)

Comment: @TheLostMind Not *to* an object, but if a local variable is the only place holding a reference to an object, and if method execution is past the last point where the variable is read, then the object may be considered unreachable. There is, of course, no guarantee that a runtime will actually collect it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that local variables referencing objects **are** garbage collected if they are no longer needed. However, this does not apply when debugging. I guess the debugger keeps a reference to it, but in regular execution there is no need for it.

Try executing the following code, and see what happens.

```
Object o1 = new Object();
System.out.println(o1);
WeakReference<Object> wr = new WeakReference<Object>(o1);
System.gc();
System.out.println(wr.get());
```

My output (without debugger):

```
java.lang.Object@20662d1
null
```

My output (with debugger):

```
java.lang.Object@206b4fc
java.lang.Object@206b4fc
```

It would therefore appear that the earlier references are garbage collected, even when the local method is still on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the object (i.e. 'a') in the first recursion marked for garbage collection once the second recursion begins or does it need to be explicitly marked null since the outer function never finishes because of the recursion.

The answer is ... it is platform dependent.

The variable `a` is still in-scope until the declaring instance of `doWork()` returns.  On the other hand, it is obvious to us that by the time the `a` variable cannot influence the computation once we reach the recursive call, and (in theory) that means that the GC no longer needs to consider it for the purposes of determining reachability.

So, it boils down to whether or not the JVM is smart enough to realize that `a` doesn't matter any more.  That is platform dependent.  And as another Answer notes, running with a debugger attached can change this.

---

Another Answer mentions tail-call optimization.  Certainly, if a JVM did implement this optimization, then the "old" `a` would conceptually be replaced by a "new" one in the optimized "call".  However, no HotSpot JVM (at least up to Java 8) implements tail-call optimization because the optimization would interfere with Java code that relies on being able to count stack frames; e.g. security code.

However, if this particular code *was* a significant storage leak, then it would most likely be moot, because (absent tail-call optimization) the code is likely to give you a `StackOverflowError` before it fills the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You should asume that all local references are alive as long as the method itself is in the call stack. This means you get one alive reference to a for each recursion.

It might happen that the runtime sees, that the slot for variable a can be overwritten when it is no longer accessed. In that case it becomes unreachable even when doWork() has not returned yet. However you cannot rely on this. It would help to `a = null;` right after last usage of a.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, recursion is done by pushing the actual frame (local variable set) onto the stack and opening a new frame for the new execution.

The object in the heap are still referred by variables in the frame that has been pushed to the stack and that means that, for the GC, the object is still "live".

However many compilers (and I assume javac as well) are able to recognize and unfold tail recursions like the one in the example, thus simplifying the recursion quite a lot a freeing many resources.

In general, however, recursion uses up a lot of stack and heap space and that's why using recursion is not always a good idea.

Comment: I've never seen any evidence o Tail Call Optimization on the JVM. In fact, I am quite sure it does not exist.

Comment: Well, it is quite the rare case so maybe it's pointless to have in a real compiler. I'm quite sure however that gcc with the max optimization setting on does some form of tail recursion unfolding.

Comment: gcc is a completely different world... Just think how the thread stack trace could be preserved under TCO.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good approach to actively get rid of references if you want garbage collection, by setting your variables to `null`. However, do not forget that objects might contain event registration, separate threads and so on, so if you want to garbage-collect an object, you must make sure there is no leak in their references. This is not the case with `Object`, but it can happen with instances from other classes. As for the question though, I believe that it is not garbage-collected unless you get rid actively from its reference, but I have not tested this with all Java versions.